# Do controls in Firefox receive mouse events when their CSS visible property is false?

Tags: css, firefox, drop-down-menu, mouseevent, visibility

I'm having a problem with FIREFOX.  I have an invisible list control over a drop-down control (html 'select').  Don't mind why, but I will say that the over-layer is a pop-up that appears as part of another custom control.

Even though it's hidden, it's preventing me from clicking on the underlying drop-down control, making the underlying control seem disabled.  It's not disabled though, because I can tab over to it.  I just can't click on it.  I know it's the overlay causing the problem, because I moved the underlying control off to the side and it works again.

Is this a bug in Firefox?  This isn't like setting a translucency value; it's disabling rendering of the control altogether, so I don't think such an invisible control should be intercepting mouse events.
This behavior does not occur in Internet Explorer.

Perhaps there is some other CSS property I can set in JavaScript to toggle its mouse event capturing ability along with its visibility.

```
dd = document.getElementById('lstStudents');
if (dd.style.visibility == 'hidden') dd.style.visibility = 'visible'; else dd.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Update: I just read a description for the CSS visibility value "hidden" that read "The element is invisible (but still takes up space)".  So I guess I'll have to set it's height to zero along with setting it's visibility to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you making the 'invisible list control' invisible. Sample code?

Comment: CSS visibility property, toggled through javascript.  The initial style of the control has the visibility set to "hidden" before any JavaScript is ever run on it.  This is a CLEAR difference in behavior between IE and Firefox (3.5.5).

Answer (score 1):

change your over-layer control's z-index to, say, -1. style="z-index: -1;"  This will place it underneath everything, allowing direct access to drop-down.  You might have to dynamically change the z-index to bring over-layer back on top when visible.

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Placing it underneath everything is a neat idea, and since it's a popup, I could easily set the z-index to some very high value when it's visible.  However, it bothers me that it may be receiving events while it's supposed to be hidden, and I don't want to have to set two properties (visibility and z-index), nor do I want to be setting one of those properties to an arbitrary value like a "high" z-index.

Comment: Also, this won't work in my situation (and probably many others), because the control is nested inside div elements, which all have thier own z-indexes, so setting the z-index on the item won't make a difference as far as it's overlapping other controls that aren't in the same div.

Answer (score 0):

How are you hiding the element? If I remember it right, "visibility: hidden" is supposed to (rightly) work the way you describe, while "display: none" will banish rendering altogether.

If that's not the cause, can you confirm using Web Developer Toolbar that it is indeed the invisible control that is causing the problem and not another that has opacity set to 0 or something?

Comment: Display none would probably work, but then I'm stuck trying to restore to a display value that could be any number of values (block, inline, etc.), and I don't want to hard-code that original value in my javascript.  I need a boolean property like visiblility.  It saddens me that this works in IE but not Firefox.

Comment: I think FF is right here and IE is wrong, at least as far as I understand the "visibility" attribute. How about storing the original display value in the element?

Comment: This seems to be a good work-around for now and it's what I'm using, but I'm not going to mark it as the answer until I ascertain the correct behavior, since it's different between IE and Firefox.  This kind of trouble is why I use Flash, which just work beautifully for web-based interfaces.  It has specific enabled and mouseEnabled properties, in addition to visible and alpha properties.

Comment: oh how about *visibility:collapse*?

Comment: Collapse may be supported only in internet explorer 8 according to this similar thread on this whole "visibility vs display" issue...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852321/visibilitycollapse-in-javascript/852346#852346

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done popup boxes before in Firefox was with CSS properties.

```
z-index: 500;
display: block;
```

to show an element, and

```
z-index: -10;
display: none;
```

to hide it.

Now. My values for z-index are extreme, but that's just what I chose.  This works for me, but my app targeted Firefox specifically; aaaaand I'm using the display property, which you stated you want to avoid.

If you're concerned about using display:block or display:hidden, I think maybe you could try to play with positioning, or sizing the element.

Either make the popup element absolutely positioned and move it offscreen when invisible, or maybe try to make it 0px width and 0px height when invisible.  That's two things I would potentially explore if I still had problems.  I'm not sure if I would recommend these as best solutions though.

Really consider how many instances of your popup elements will have different display values, I found in my case to be using only two types, 'none', and 'block'.  Maybe manipulating the display property will be enough for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Z-index won't help when elements are nested in different container div elements.  Display:none is actually the most appealing work-around, and simply setting the height to zero would also be a nice workaround.  I actually used to use only the height property to hide it, but it was showing up funny without visibility set to hidden.  I got rid of the code to adjust the hight, figuring it was overkill since I was making it invisible... and that's when I encountered this problem.  I'm sticking with using display:none for now since it seems to work correctly on both browsers.